# Python log error refers to incorrect line in function

Tags: python-3.x, logging, error-logging

A newbie here, will appreciate some help.

Below is a sample code which defines and calls a function. I have deliberately put an error in the code in line 7 to see how the logging behaves when the program hits an error.

```
def addition(a,b):

    logging.getLogger(__name__).info("LOG")
    start = time.time()

    try:
        print("the first number is \n" + str(a))
        print("and the second one is \n" + str(b))
        prin(a+b)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger("LOG").error('this is an error,'+ str(e))


    end = time.time()
    logging.getLogger("LOG").log(20,'Function 1 Completed, time_finished: '
                                     + str(end - start)
                                     + ' seconds, '
                                     + str(50))

addition(2,3)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
the first number is

2

and the second one is 

3

2019-03-20 18:57:31,826 MAIN_LOGGER ERROR 0024 this is an error,name 'prin' is not defined
```

---

In essence, I want the log error message to display the actual line where the error is occurring rather than when I call the log function.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `exception`, not `error` when printing a traceback to the log to get the full traceback.

```
except Exception as e:
    logging.getLogger("MAIN_LOGGER").exception('Could not perform translation')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to show the line where the error occurs:

`print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e)`

Using your exemple, it would be like this:

```
import sys

def addition(a,b):
    try:
        print("the first number is \n" + str(a))
        print("and the second one is \n" + str(b))
        prin(a+b)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e)
```